# Go to current date, in calendar with a month on each tab, when file is opened

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel spreadsheet where I created a calendar that has each month on separate tabs (named August, September, October, etc.).

I want the file to open then automatically move the cursor to the current date, whatever tab that may be.
I also want a button that while working in the file, can be pressed and will bring the user to the tab with the current date.

I started with creating a button on each page that when pressed will bring it to the current date using this macro.

```vb
Sub CurrentDate_Click()

    Dim dateRng As Range
    Dim DateCell As Range
    Dim WorkSht As Worksheet
    Dim dateStr As String
    Application.Goto Worksheets("August").Range("A1")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each WorkSht In Worksheets
        WorkSht.Select
        'Set daterng = Range("A:A")
        Set dateRng = WorkSht.UsedRange
        'daterng.Select
        For Each DateCell In dateRng
            DateCell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Select
            On Error Resume Next
            dateStr = DateCell.Value
            If dateStr = Date Then
                DateCell.Select
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    Next WorkSht
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'Worksheets(1).Select
End Sub
```

How do I make it generic so that when the current date is not in August, the button still works?
I had to change the August in "Application.Goto Worksheets("August").Range("A1")" from Sheet 1 to get it to work initially.

How can the macro run when the workbook opens to bring the user to the current date without having to press the button?
I thought `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()` might work, but get errors when I tried to add that.

I initially had the macro in a module, then added one individually to each monthly spreadsheet and changed the `Application.Goto Worksheets` line to each respective months name, but still get an error.

> "Expected End Sub"

I tried adding another `End Sub` and got the same error.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Sub CurrentDate_Click()

    Dim dateRng As Range
    Dim DateCell As Range
    Dim WorkSht As Worksheet
    Dim dateStr As String
    Application.Goto Worksheets("September").Range("A1")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each WorkSht In Worksheets
        WorkSht.Select
        'Set daterng = Range("A:A")
        Set dateRng = WorkSht.UsedRange
        'daterng.Select
        For Each DateCell In dateRng
            DateCell.Activate
            ActiveCell.Select
            On Error Resume Next
            dateStr = DateCell.Value
            If dateStr = Date Then
                DateCell.Select
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    Next WorkSht
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'Worksheets(1).Select
End Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Workbook_Open` event to get your expected result. It is triggered when users open the workbook.

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim sMonth As String
    Dim oSht As Worksheet, c As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    sMonth = Format(Date, "MMMM")
    Set oSht = Sheets(sMonth)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If oSht Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Can't find sheet " & sMonth, vbCritical
    Else
        oSht.Select
        For Each c In oSht.UsedRange
            If VBA.IsDate(c) Then
                If CLng(c) = CLng(Date) Then
                    c.Select
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        Next
        MsgBox "Can't find " & Format(Date, "yyyy/mm/dd") & " on sheet " & sMonth, vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Exception warning msgbox

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using `Select` and `ActiveCell`, and use fully qualified objects instead.

Instead of looping through your entire range `For Each DateCell In dateRng`, you can use `Find` which will give you the same result but a lot faster.

I've added some more comments in the code below.

You need to add this code in your *ThisWorkbook* module.

***Modified Code***

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim ShtName As String
Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim FindRng As Range, FindDateRng As Range

' set up worksheet object and trap possible error
On Error Resume Next
ShtName = Format(Date, "mmmm")
Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ShtName)
On Error GoTo 0
If Sht Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Can't find worksheet named " & ShtName & "' in MACRO workbook", vbCritical

Else
    With Sht
        .Select
    
        ' --- Use Find --> Faster Code run-time ---
        Set FindRng = .Cells
        Set FindDateRng = FindRng.Find(What:=CDate(Date), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=True)
        ' if Date found, select the cell
        If Not FindDateRng Is Nothing Then
            FindDateRng.Select
        Else
            MsgBox "Unable to find '" & Format(Date, "m/d/yyyy") & "' in '" & .Name & "' worksheet", vbCritical, "Critical Error!"
            Exit Sub
        End If

    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! So I am using an Excel calendar template that has this formula in each of the numbered date fields =DaysAndWeeks+DATE(CalendarYear,5,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(CalendarYear,5,1),(WeekStart="Monday")+1)+1

Comment: I couldn't edit that last comment after 5 mins so pls disregard that one. 

Thank you! So I am using an Excel calendar template that has this formula in each of the numbered date fields. The formulas change each week but are the same for each day within each week. They are as follows:

Comment: =DaysAndWeeks+DATE(CalendarYear,5,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(CalendarYear,5,1),(WeekStart="Monday")+1)+1
=DaysAndWeeks+DATE(CalendarYear,5,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(CalendarYear,5,1),(WeekStart="Monday")+1)+8
=DaysAndWeeks+DATE(CalendarYear,5,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(CalendarYear,5,1),(WeekStart="Monday")+1)+15
=DaysAndWeeks+DATE(CalendarYear,5,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(CalendarYear,5,1),(WeekStart="Monday")+1)+22
=DaysAndWeeks+DATE(CalendarYear,5,1)-WEEKDAY(DATE(CalendarYear,5,1),(WeekStart="Monday")+1)+29

Comment: Is it possible to tailor your macro to work with these formulas somehow or do I need to edit the template to change the format to the mm/dd/yyyy? The tab names are all the respective month names. Thanks again

Comment: I am new to this tool so apologies if I did something wrong, but does Shai Rado see these comments? Am I able to ask questions like this? I need guidance on how to include the references to the formulas above in the macro edits that Shai provided me. Thanks.